# What's this attribute represented by a purple skull?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I was shopping when I noticed this ring has an icon that isn't in character's primary statistics.
[image: A ring with a one of an attribute represented by a purple skull.]

What's that icon mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That icon represents [Necromantic Defense](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Necromantic_Damage_Resistance#Resistance_Types), not damage.

Icons in circles like that represent [defensiveness](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Damage_resistance) and make you more resistant to attacks of that kind.

Icons in squares represent [damage](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Damage) and apply when you attack using your weapons (or feet).

Comment: The icon is the same; the shape *around* the icon changes based on whether or not it's defense or damage.

Comment: True, however the previous answer is still not correct.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely correct.  I am in error.  I always mix those two things up when I play.  I pretty much always have to have the wiki open to tell all the symbols apart...

Comment: @agent86 - I still have to check all the primary attributes every time they come up >.< for some reason I can't get them fixed in my seive like memory.